# Xcode 5.1.1 Simulator in Use error display when simulator is not used

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, ios-simulator, xcode5.1

Ever since I downloaded the update to Xcode 5.1.1 I keep getting this error message more often then not when my simulator is **not in use and even when I quit the simulator[image]**:

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Quit the Simulator & Xcode also. And again open your Xcode and run. And delete your cache memory from IOS 7.1 Simulater

Comment: That's really the only solution I found for now but doing this every 5 minutes annoys me and slows me down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually fixed this problem was upgrading my OSX to Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

Force quit your simulator as well as you xcode

Press: Command +option(alt) + ece

Quit Xcode and iOS simulator

Restart xcode

Hope your problem will solved by this.

Comment: This helps and what I have been doing so far but I have to do this every 5 minutes which does not make any sense

Comment: ok i found new solution for this go to your project built setting and fine Build Active Architecture and change it to yes by default it is yes for debug and no for release

Comment: are you opening two projects simultanously

Comment: Clean the project, Reset Simulator, Delete 'Derived Data'.

Comment: Not opening two projects simultaniasly. Will try the clean

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52756/discussion-between-anonymous-and-michal-shatz)